# Inserting Code Between Region Trivia With Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

How can I insert a variable declaration after a region directive in Roslyn? I'd like to be able to do something like going from this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    #region myRegion
    #endregion
}
```

to this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    #region myRegion
    private const string myData = "somedata";
    #endregion 
}
```

I can't seem to find any examples that deal with trivia in this manner.

Comment: Why don't you provide some code how you're trying to generate this snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite tricky to do with a [CSharpSyntaxRewriter](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxRewriter.cs), because both the `#region <name>` and `#endregion` end up in the same `SyntaxTriviaList`, which you'd have to split out and figure out what to create instead. The simplest way to not bother with all the intricacies, is to create the corresponding `TextChange` and modify the `SourceText`.

```
var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(
@"class MyClass
{
    #region myRegion
    #endregion
}");

// get the region trivia
var region = tree.GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes(descendIntoTrivia: true)
    .OfType<RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax>()
    .Single();

// modify the source text
tree = tree.WithChangedText(
    tree.GetText().WithChanges(
        new TextChange(
            region.GetLocation().SourceSpan,
            region.ToFullString() + "private const string myData = \"somedata\";")));
```

After that, `tree` is:

```
class MyClass 
{
    #region myRegion
private const string myData = "somedata";
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**m0sa's** answer works for empty regions but it cannot replace existing code which is the likely reason to need to this i.e. rerunning a code-generation tool.

Achieving this requires finding the full extent of the region. This is also made difficult because the target file can contain multiple nested regions. To do this I process all directives and build a hierarchy of regions:

```cs
public class RegionInfo
{
    public RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax Begin;
    public EndRegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax End;
    public RegionInfo Parent;
    public List<RegionInfo> Children = new List<RegionInfo>();
    public string Name => this.Begin.EndOfDirectiveToken.ToFullString().Trim();
}

public static class CodeMutator
{   
    public static string ReplaceRegion(string existingCode, string regionName, string newCode)
    {
        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(existingCode);

        var region = CodeMutator.GetRegion(syntaxTree, regionName);

        if (region == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Cannot find region named {regionName}");
        }

        return 
            existingCode
                .Substring(0, region.Begin.FullSpan.End) +
            newCode +
            Environment.NewLine +
            existingCode
                .Substring(region.End.FullSpan.Start);
    }

    static RegionInfo GetRegion(SyntaxTree syntaxTree, string regionName) =>
        CodeMutator.GetRegions(syntaxTree)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == regionName);

    static List<RegionInfo> GetRegions(SyntaxTree syntaxTree)
    {
        var directives = syntaxTree
            .GetRoot()
            .DescendantNodes(descendIntoTrivia: true)
            .OfType<DirectiveTriviaSyntax>()
            .Select(x => (x.GetLocation().SourceSpan.Start, x))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
            .ToList();

        var allRegions = new List<RegionInfo>();
        RegionInfo parent = null;

        foreach (var directive in directives)
        {
            if (directive.Item2 is RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax begin)
            {
                var next = new RegionInfo() {Begin = begin, Parent = parent};

                allRegions.Add(next);
                parent?.Children.Add(next);

                parent = next;
            }
            else if (directive.Item2 is EndRegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax end)
            {
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    Log.Error("Unmatched end region");
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.End = end;
                    parent = parent.Parent;
                }
            }
        }

        return allRegions;
    }
}
```